# Editing product configurable

Tags: magento-enterprise, configurable-product

I'm creating configurable product, but when i create the product i have 2 simple product to associate.

I make this code to create the product(resume):

```
$mprodc = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$mprodc->setTypeId(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_CONFIGURABLE);
//setting other attributes(not improtant)
...
//here's the important part
$mprodc->setConfigurableProductsData($simple);
$mprodc->setConfigurableAttributesData($attributeData);
$mprodc->setCanSaveConfigurableAttributes(true);
$mprodc->save();
```

Ok its work like a charm, on $simple and $attributeData i should pass the apropriate formated array to works but i figure it without trouble.
Until this part i create the configurable product associated with other 2 simple product and set the attribute and price difference(if it have) properly.

The problem is when i need to add one or more simple product on this already created product configurable.
I can't use the same code that i used to create the product (don't know why but doens't work)

So i'm using this code:

```
$sku = 123; //sku from the simple product i'll associate
$config = $collection->getFirstItem();
$ct = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_type_configurable');
$idsSimple = $ct->getChildrenIds($config->getId());//get the id's from the already associated products
$productChild = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$sku);
$idf = $productChild->getId();
$idsS[0][$idf] = (string)$idf;
$idsS = $idsS[0];
$ct->saveProducts($config, $idsS);
```

But i can't figure how i set the price difference to this new products, i know how i can do that directy on the database, but isn't a good pratice.

Someone can help?